# pass not skipping the rest of the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm making a small program where user creates an account but for some reason in this part of the code pass does nothing 
can somebody please explain this?

```
def create_password():
    while True:
        password = '#'
        not_allowed_characters = '!#¤%&/()=?^\'.,<>'
        for c in list(password):
            0 + 0
        if c in not_allowed_characters:
            print(c + ' is not allowed')
            pass #pass does nothing how can i fix this
        if 0 is 0:
            print(1)
create_password()
```

Comment: What did you expect `pass` to do?

Comment: `pass` is actually for *nothing*.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement pass is a null operation — when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed,

Comment: how can i make it to not run the rest of the loop without breaking it

Comment: @pythonprogrammer use `continue`.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to reflect what you want to accomplish. As it is now, the question will be of no use for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pass` does nothing *by definition*. That's what it's for: as a no-op, a placeholder for when the syntax requires a statement but you don't want to do anything.

I suspect what you want here is `continue`, which will loop.